# Natural JOIN with two foreign keys

Tags: mysql, select, natural-join

i have those two tables

```
id | name |
___________
 1 | John |
 2 | Mike |

id | id_name1 | id_name2
________________________
 1 |     2    |    1
 2 |     1    |  null
```

first tables primary key is ID in second table i have two foreign keys ID_NAME1 and ID_NAME2 that they reference to primary key from first table.
After using

```
SELECT table1.name, table2.id FROM table1 NATURAL JOIN table 2
```

i get

```
John 1
John 2
Mike 1
Mike 2
```

but i want

```
John 1
John 2
Mike 2
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: The result you are getting is correct with `natural join` however your expected result is something different, could you explain a bit on the expected result.

Comment: why is it correct? it is showing 2 by Mike even his id isnt in second row of table 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `natural join` what you expect I guess is:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c9b1d/7

```
SELECT table1.name, table2.id
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.id = table2.id_name1
  OR table1.id = table2.id_name2
  ORDER BY table1.id,table2.id
```

Comment: isnt there a way withou using names of rows id_name1 and id_name2?

Comment: as I know, no there is no such way

Comment: ok your answer is the best it do what i want so thank you saved me a lot of time ;)